# Where is my Makefile looking for c++ headers?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake

I am working with opencv 3.0, and getting the following error:

```
 error: 
      'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

So I looked in `/usr/local/include/` for the file path and was able to find it. This tells me that my make file must be looking in the wrong place for header files. The make file is generated by `cmake` using the command `cmake .` from the directory containing `CMakeLists.txt` So I figure cmake must be generating the make file with the wrong path for headers.

So does anyone know where I can find what path `cmake` is trying to use? Or can I find this from the make file generated by `cmake`?

In CMakeLists.txt there is a line: `target_link_libraries( BlobDetector ${OpenCV_LIBS} )` is the variable `OpenCV_LIBS` the path name used? If so how can I find what this path is?

Comment: Do you try to add the path to the *Additional Include Directories* field in your C++ project's Properties?

Comment: Use `make VERBOSE=1` then you see the paths which are passed to the compiler.

Comment: The line you need is `include_directories()`. Make sure `${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}` is passed there.